# BottomSheet with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have a RecyclerView (A). When I select an item a second RecyclerView(B) appears as  BottomSheet. The problem is  when I scroll the RecyclerView B I can see that the RecyclerView A is scrolling too. How can I fix this? The root layout is CoordinayorLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at example with custom Behavior [example](https://github.com/fedorenkoalex/bottomsheetrecycler)